# generic polimorph function based on argumens passed

Tags: r

I am looking for a method (maybe S3 programming) that allow this function choose a method based on the arguments that is passed. 
I thought defining an S3 class the function would choose the right method, but i noticed a group of arguments doesn't do an object's class and cannot define it as is.
How can I do create this polymorphism's logic?

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

sample <- data.frame(
  gp = c("a", "a", "b"),
  claims = c(30, 23, 23),
  workers = c(265, 354, 124),
  DY = c(0, 1, 0)
)

# generic IBNR function

FC_IBNR_TOT <- function(
  claims,
  ...
){
  library(dplyr)

  UseMethod("FC_IBNR_TOT", claims)
}

FC_IBNR_TOT.default <- function(
  claims,
  workers,
  ...
){

  if_else(sum(workers) == 0, 0, sum(claims) / sum(workers) * 12)
}

FC_IBNR_TOT.simple <- function(
  claims,
  workers,
  DY, # develoment year
  FDA = 1.035,
  ...
){

  if_else(
    sum(workers) == 0, 
    0, 
    sum(
      claims * 
        if_else(
          DY == 0, 
          FDA,
          1
        )
    )/ sum(workers) * 12 
  )
}

expected <- sample %>% 
  group_by(
    gp
  ) %>% 
  summarise(
    frec_1 = FC_IBNR_TOT.default(
      claims, workers
    ),
    frec_2 = FC_IBNR_TOT.simple(
      claims, workers, DY
    )
  )

expected

desired <- sample %>% 
  group_by(
    gp
  ) %>% 
  summarise(
    frec_1 = FC_IBNR_TOT(
      claims = claims, workers = workers
    ),
    frec_2 = FC_IBNR_TOT(
      claims = claims, workers = workers, DY = DY
    )
  )

desired
```

Note that the desired code ever points to `FC_IBNR_TOT.default`.
I need call the function as its generic name `FC_IBNR_TOT` (not `FC_IBNR_TOT.default` neither `FC_IBNR_TOT.simple`)

Comment: `FC_IBNR_TOT.simple` will only be called on objects of class `simple`. I don't see any such class.

Comment: Yes, I think you misunderstood how method dispatch functions. in S3, only the class of the first argument is dispatched on. What you want to do is different behavior depending on how many arguments are given. (your arguments by the way are column names of the data frame you are using ... these are not objects with specific class ... so you want actually let your function behave differently depending on how many arguments you give).

Comment: yes, but maybe my function behave different  when f(a = a, b = b, c = c) and  f(a = a, b = b, d = d) both with three args.

Comment: you have to manually dispatch with `if` `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to dispatch it like this.
However, there is still a problem with summarize().
But I couldn't resolve it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

sample <- data.frame(
  gp = c("a", "a", "b"),
  claims = c(30, 23, 23),
  workers = c(265, 354, 124),
  DY = c(0, 1, 0)
)


FC_IBNR_TOT <- function(claims, workers, DY=NULL, FDA=1.035, ...) {
  if (is.null(DY)) {
    ifelse(sum(workers) == 0, 0, sum(claims) / sum(workers) * 12)
  } else {
    ifelse(sum(workers) == 0,
                   0,
                   sum(claims * ifelse(DY == 0, FDA, 1)) / sum(workers) * 12)
  }
}

desired <- sample %>%
  group_by(gp) %>%
  summarise(frec_1 = FC_IBNR_TOT(claims, workers),
            frec_2 = FC_IBNR_TOT(claims, workers, DY))
desired
```